# How to restrict adding solution to source control permission in team foundation server?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019

We are managing a large group of developers that are developing a variety kinds of projects that use **`Team Foundation Server`**  , We need to restrict some of the developers permissions and just give them to admins .

In the first place, `Add` `solution to source control` should be claimed from developers and it should be available for administrators , they should just be able to have `check in` and `check out` permission.

[image]

I red following document from Microsoft but couldn't how to set such a permission.

> [Manage Tfs Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/project-admin-tutorial?toc=%2Ftfs%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fserver%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops-2020)

**Update:**
What we want to do : developers should fill an application and describe about their new projects they want to be added to source controller and then we make a `blank solution` and add it to source control, Now developers can add their projects to blank solution and **check in** their changes.

Hope someone could help me here or refer me to a useful document

I appreciate your attention.

Comment: The "Add Solution to Source Control" option just prepares all files in the solution for check in (and if a workspace is not configured, it handles that first).  It would be the same as the developer running `tf add . /r` from the solution folder.  Are you saying you want to deny permissions to add any new files to the workspace?

Comment: i just want admins have permission to add solution to source controller, but other new files inside solution could be added by developers themselves, just because adding new solution to tfs should go through some steps by admins.

Comment: So you want policies specifically defined for files with the `.sln` extension?

Comment: I don't think so...adding solution to source control should be a privilege  for admins not developers , Although developers should be able to add any kind of file or project to newly created blank solution.

Comment: What is the thing you're trying to prevent happening by letting developers work with source control normally?

Comment: Just infrastructure admins should be able to add solution to tfs because there are more than 30 developers that are creating projects and we need to have some detail about new project before adding to tfs.,It's actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

> developers can add their projects to blank solution and check in their changes and administrators can click the button Add solution to source control to add the solution, right?

If we want to [add the solution to TFS Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs?view=azure-devops-2020#add-the-solution-to-azure-repos), the steps are: Add your solution to version control->Add a comment and check in the solution, then we could see the solution in TFS

The button `Add solution to source control` just add the project to mapping folder instead of TFS repo, we could not configure the TFS permission to restrict adding solution to source control.

If we need to restrict check-in permission, we could set the repo or repo folder permission. Check the pic below.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much , is it possible to restrict check in permision for .sln file or something like this?, you know i'm looking for a way that just admins have right to add solution to tfs but developer have check in right in solution

Comment: Hi @Abolfazl, We cannot restrict check in permission for .sln file, we could only restrict check in permission for folder.

Comment: Also you could check the feature [gated check-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/check-folder-controlled-by-gated-check-build-process?view=azure-devops), It will run the build and will not check in the update code until build succeeds. Then we could list the check in file and check if it contain .sln file, if yes, fail this build. In addition, we could configure admins permission and ensure that the permission Override check-in validation by build permission set to Allow. Then admins could bypass the gated check-in requirement